# (MVC) Regex: starts with, ends with and can only contain

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm writing a data annotation in an MVC application. I need to apply a RegEx for the following:

- Must start with an alphabetic char,
- Must end with an alphabetic char,
- Can only contain alphabetic, periods/full stops, spaces, apostrophes
  and hyphens.

I'm trying the following and would appreciate a point in the right direction:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z|.| |'|-]*(?:[A-Za-z])*$
```

Effectively it's appearing to do what I want, EXCEPT that it allows periods, hyphens, spaces and apostrophes at the end of the string. I thought I had cracked it, but instead, I'm turning to you SO.

Any help would be very much appreciated!!

EDIT:
Just in case anyone is after the solution to a very similar problem:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z|.| |'|-]*[A-Za-z]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the lookahead at the very end of your regex and you should be done.

`/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z|.| |'|-]*[A-Za-z]$/g`

What you want to make sure, is that the very last letter of your match is a letter, so there is no need to have a lookahead. You can just match it like you would do with any normal letter.

Comment: Spot on, that saved me a lot of time, thanks! I'm not sure what the / and /g were meant to do but I removed that and the expression has passed my tests.